# How to show two varieties are NOT birationally equivalent?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

This is an exercise from Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms by Cox et al.

**Some backgroud**

It comes from a problem showing that $Q=V(x^2+y^2-z^2-1)$, a hyperboloid, and $W=V(x+1)$, a plane, are birationally equivalent by two rational maps that define a one-to-one correspondence between $Q-V_Q(x+1)=Q-V$ and $W-V_W(y^2-z^2+4)=W-H$. The two rational maps are 
$$\phi: Q-V \rightarrow W-H, \quad (x,y,z)\mapsto (-1, \frac{-2y}{x-1}, \frac{-2z}{x-1})\\
\psi: W-H \rightarrow Q-V, \quad (-1, a,b)\mapsto (\frac{a^2-b^2-4}{z^2-b^2+4},\frac{4a}{a^2-b^2+4},\frac{4b}{a^2-b^2+4})$$

Then it asks to show that although $Q$ and $W$ are birationally equivalent, the excluded part from the map

> $V$ and $H$, as varieties, are neither isomorphic nor birationally equivalent.

**My attempt**

It is equivalent to show that the two varieties $V=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2| x=\pm y\}$ and $H=\{(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2 | a^2-b^2+4=0\}$ are not birationally equivalent.

Suppose there exists rationally mappings $\phi: H\rightarrow V$ and $\psi: V\rightarrow H$ such that they are inverse of each other.

**My question:**

I then defined them and set up the equations by the definition of the varieties. It makes it more complicated and I don't know where to go.

I also noticed one of them is two lines intersecting with each other, the other is two branches of a hyperbola. I wonder if that tells anything, because the author didn't mention how to identify equivalence using geometry.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do they really work over $\mathbb{R}$? It might help to give the number of the exercise too.

Comment: @Hoot: Thank you again! It is Chapter 5 Section 5, number 14. I just figured maybe one of them is irreducible, the other is not. I will try that and get back. If you meant the first part, yes the mappings work over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I think he was asking if this exercise is about real varieties (as suggested by the paragraph you labelled "my attempt") instead of complex varieties (which would be more common).

Comment: @A.P.: I see. I believe it is about real varieties. This section contains many examples in $\mathbb{R}$ of which the author relates the mappings with pictures. This exercise concerns one of them.

Comment: Actually, how do you define birational equivalence for non-irreducible varieties? I've only seen it defined for irreducible varieties. Also [the book you are using](https://books.google.it/books?id=yL7yCAAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=Ideals%2C%20Varieties%20and%20Algorithms%20by%20Cox&pg=PA271#v=onepage&q=Ideals,%20Varieties%20and%20Algorithms%20by%20Cox&f=false) seems to define rational maps only between irreducible varieties.

Comment: @A.P.: You are right. It's silly of me. I should just state one of them is reducible.